# Why array unexpectedly changes in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular+laravel project. In one component I received one variable from database which is object array. I do not change it just looping through that variable but it changes automatically whenever the function looping called. I am not sure why it works.
Is it related with Async or observable subscribe?

```
...
allOrder: { date_time: Date,tableID: string, identity: string, paid:boolean, orders: Order[]}[] = [];

...
constructor(private basicService: BasicService) { 
    this.getOrder();
}
...
getOrder(): void {
   this.basicService.getOrders().subscribe(items => {
      items.map(item => {
          this.allOrder.push(item); 
        }
      })
  })
}
...
onAllOrder() {
    var displayAllOrder = [];
    var displayNum = 0; 
    this.allOrder.map(itemsAll => {
      itemsAll.orders.map(itemAll => {
        displayAllOrder.map(groupItem => {
          if(groupItem.productID == itemAll.productID){
            groupItem.num = groupItem.num + itemAll.num;
            displayNum = 1;
          }
        })
        if(displayNum == 0) displayAllOrder.push(itemAll);
        displayNum = 0;
      })
    });
}
```

I do not change variable allOrder but it changes whenever I call onAllOrder function.
Please help me.

Comment: use `forEach` for array looping, not `map`

Comment: what kind of changes ?? unexpected changes in the object or length ..?

Comment: is best to use key let instead of var, (scooped variable)

Comment: Changes happen in the num option of allOrder arrary.                                 groupItem.num = groupItem.num + itemAll.num;

Answer (score 2):

All though Array.map creates new array, the objects in former and latter holds the same reference. So, any changes to the object will change the original array.

Here, you can use forEach instead.

```
this.allOrder.forEach(itemsAll => {
  itemsAll.orders.forEach(itemAll => {
    displayAllOrder.forEach(groupItem => {
      if(groupItem.productID == itemAll.productID){
        groupItem.num = groupItem.num + itemAll.num;
        displayNum = 1;
      }
    })
    if(displayNum == 0) displayAllOrder.push(itemAll);
    displayNum = 0;
  })
});
```

Comment: I used forEach method but still changes the array.